# How do you get TikZ to show the proper notation for a discontinuity on a graph? When I do it, it just creates a v-shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to use TikZ to graph the function f(x)=(X+1) with a discontinuity when x=2 by multiplying f by (x-2)/(x-2) like this: f(x)=(x+1)(x-2)/(x-2).

When I try to do so, Tikz gives me an error saying I asked it to divide by 0, when the intention was for it to show a discontinuity on the function for that domain value.

Can someone with some more experience please help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,yscale=0.75]

\def \xmin {-3}
\def \xmax {3}
\def \ymin {-1.5}
\def \ymax {3}
    
\path[draw,->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0);
\path[draw,->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax);
\node[below] at (\xmax,0) {$x$};
\node[left] at (0,\ymax) {$y$};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {0};
    
\clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
\draw[domain=\xmin:\xmax,color=blue] plot ({\x}, {(\x-2)*(\x+1)/(\x-2)});
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sure you can use `pgfplots` to plot this function  (you even load the package, but do not use it). This function will look no different than just the original line. The question is: What would you like to happen at `x=2`?

Comment: You need to EXCLUDE x=2 for an obvious reason, as the error message states. Usually such points are marked by, e.g., an empty circle (which you can superimpose with Tikz).

Comment: 1. Thanks for the advice, I will try to make the code compliable.  2. The reason I am trying to graph with TikZ instead of pgfplots is because I sometimes like to use shapes and lines in my graphs which is difficult to do in pfg. What I want to happen is for the discontinuity to show up as a little circle like in my book. 3. Thanks for the response, how do I superimpose that circle and is there a way to make it so the plot does this itself for functions with lots of discontinuities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make sense to say that it is easier to draw lines and shapes in TikZ than in PGFPlots. PGFPlots is build on top of TikZ, so it is the exact same way. PGFPlots is at a higher level than TikZ while PGF is a low level code that is not needed for this.

Obviously, I can not know what you do in "your book". Here is a circle at the discontinuity point:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-3, xmax=3,
ymin=-1.5, xmax=3,
axis lines=center,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=2] {x+1};
\addplot[mark=*, fill=white, forget plot] coordinates{(2,3)};
\draw[red] (1,1) -- (3,2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Linear graph with red line and circle mark]

There is no way to do this automatically. PGFPlots and Tikz evaluate the function in a finite number of points set with `samples`, and draw lines(or curves) between them. PGFPlots and Tikz does not "look" at the formula and conclude anything like discontinuity points. An evaluation results in a number or `-inf`, `+inf` or `nan`. If the evaluation is not a number, then Tikz will fail, while PGFPlots will throw the point away and `jump` or `discard` the coordinate. There is no automatically way to guarantee that an evaluation is even tried at a discontinuity point.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. It's too bad that Latex can't automatically conclude discontinuities, but I am grateful to be aware of this now. I also didn't know that I could add an axis environment as well as drawings; I started learning Latex a few months ago, so please pardon my lack of knowledge in these areas. This answered my question, thank you.

Comment: I think it should be ```ymin=-1.5, ymax=3``` instead of ```ymin=-1.5, xmax=3```.